# Airflow: create a custom operator by combining existing operators

Tags: airflow

In many of my DAGs, there are 2 operators which are always used together. I wanted to create a custom operator by combining the 2 operators.

I'm aware of the SubDAGs and TaskGroups feature in Airflow, but I really wanted to create a custom operator for it. What's the best way to implement it?

Comment: TaskGroups are the best way to implement it.